# Microsoft Office Lock File Curiosity

Tags: microsoft-word

When I open a .doc file in Microsoft Word, it automatically creates a lock file.

For example, when I open `Flash.doc` from my Desktop, Word immediately creates a hidden lock file called `~$lash.doc`.

When I "switch user" to UserB and try to open `Flash.doc`, I get an "already open by UserA" message.

If I then open `Slash.doc` on the UserB account, switch back to UserA, then try to open `Slash.doc` (in addition to `Flash.doc` which is still open), I get an "already open by UserB" message.

The contents of `~$lash.doc` don't seem to change, and no additional `~$*` file is created on my Desktop.

How does Word know that UserB has the `Slash.doc` file open?

Comment: For the record I'm not having any problems with Word. This is completely a curiosity; I just want to understand the magic.

Comment: ISTR that when more than one "Owner file" (as these things are called) would have the same name, Word stores more than one user name, and some kind of hash which *could be* the file name. Sorry to be vague but i'm not in a position to investigate that - perhaps you could have a look. Also, ISTR that when the file names are short , the naming convention changes, e.g. The owner file for my.doc would be called ~$my.doc.